Longest Common Prefix implementation works fails test case on LeetCode
I'm trying to solve LeetCode problem 14. Longest Common Prefix:

Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.
If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".
Example 1:
Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"

I approached it with a Trie with the following code:
class Solution {
    static class Node {
        Node[] children;
        int childCount;
        boolean eow;

        Node(){
            children = new Node[26];
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
                children[i] = null;
            }
            eow = false;
        }
    }

    static void insertNode(String str){
        Node current = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            int index = str.charAt(i)-'a';
            if (current.children[index] == null){
                current.children[index] = new Node();
                current.childCount++;
            }
            if (i == str.length()-1){
                current.children[index].eow = true;
            }
            current = current.children[index];
        }
    }

    static String longestCommonPrefix() {
        Node current = root;
        String prefix = "";
        if (current.childCount == 0)
            return "";
        while (current.childCount == 1) {
            for (int i =0; i < 26; i++) {
                if (current.children[i] != null){
                    prefix += (char)(i+'a');
                    current = current.children[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return prefix;
    }

    static Node root = new Node();

    public static void main(String[] strs) {
        strs = new String[]{"a"};
        for (String s : strs) {
            insertNode(s);
        }
        System.out.println(longestCommonPrefix());
    }
}

It fails a test case on LeetCode when the input is a single character and single word.
For example: {"a"}
What is the mistake?

The LeetCode template expects an instance method, not a static method. You should not change that.

Note that the dsa tag is not for "data structures and algorithms."

Can you provide a link to the description page at LeetCode for this problem?

Can you, please, include a description of how it fails at LeetCode? Does it fail during compilation? Run time? If you get errors, please include exact copies of error messages. Use text copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy.

The code you've presented does not include the method expected by LeetCode:
longestCommonPrefix should not be a static method, and should take an argument.
Then there are some logic issues in your code:

root should not be a static variable that is only initialised once, but should be initialised for each run of longestCommonPrefix. Pass it as argument to insert.

insert does not place the eow flag when the argument is the empty string. You should better do this after the loop, and you can use the current reference for that.

The main loop should check that the eow flag is not set. It is not enough to check that the number of children is 1. As you ignore the eow flag, you'll miss the fact that there are shorter words that do not have the prefix you are about to return. So add this to the while condition


Here is the part of your code that need these corrections, with the minimal changes marked with a comment:
    // Add root parameter, as it should not be static
    static void insertNode(Node root, String str){
        Node current = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            int index = str.charAt(i)-'a';
            if (current.children[index] == null){
                current.children[index] = new Node();
                current.childCount++;
            }
            current = current.children[index];
        }
        // Also set the eow flag when the loop didn't make any iterations
        current.eow = true;
    }

    // Should not be static, and should have a parameter
    public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
        // root should not be a static variable, but be initialised at each
        // run of this method
        Node root = new Node();
        for (String s : strs) {
            insertNode(root, s);
        }
        Node current = root;
        String prefix = "";
        if (current.childCount == 0)
            return "";
        // Exit the loop as soon as a word ends at the current Trie node:
        while (!current.eow && current.childCount == 1) {
            for (int i =0 ; i < 26; i++) {
                if (current.children[i] != null){
                    prefix += (char)(i+'a');
                    current = current.children[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return prefix;
    }

Note that this is not a very efficient solution, not in the least because of the 26 iterations over the children array.
